Is the dimension of extension group of simple modules lead to the number of non-isomorphic indecomposable modules?
Recently, while reading a paper (On abelian  subcategories of triangulated categories by M. Linckelmann), in section 9, I came across an interesting conclusion, but I can't prove:

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional selfinjective $k$-algebra, $S$ and $T$ are two nonisomorphic simple modules. We have
$(1)$ If $\dim_k^{\phantom{1}}(\operatorname{Ext}_A^1(S,T))\geq 2$ and if $k$ is infinite. Then $A$ has infinitely many pairwise nonisomorphic uniserial modules of length $2$ with composition factors $S$ and $T$, from top to bottom.
$(2)$ Let $Y$ be a nonprojective uniserial $A$-module of length $2$ with composition factors $S$ and $T$. Then $\operatorname{End}_A(Y)\simeq k$.

I know if $k$ is algebraically closed field, the above questions are true for arbitrary algebras (not necessarily self-injective).
For $(1)$, we can consider the basic algebra $B$ of $A$, $\dim_k^{\phantom{1}}(\operatorname{Ext}_A^1(S,T))\geq 2$ lead to there are at least two arrows directions from the point corresponding to $S$ to the point corresponding to $T$ in the quiver of $B$. Thus, by indecomposable representations of Kronecker Quiver, $A$ has infinitely many pairwise nonisomorphic uniserial modules of length $2$ with composition factors $S$ and $T$, from top to bottom.
For $(2)$, Since for every nonzero homomorphism $f$ in $\operatorname{End}_A(Y)$, $f$ must be an  isomorphism. Thus $\operatorname{End}_A(Y)\simeq k$ since $k$ is algebraically closed field.
So, I want to know how to prove the above two questions is true for finite-dimensional self-injective $k$-algebra (not assume $k$ is algebraically closed field). Furthermore, are the above two questions correct for any finite-dimensional $k$-algebra (not assume $k$ is algebraically closed field).

It might interest you to know that this site uses Markdown for basic non-math formatting, e.g., *italic* renders italic, which looks better than formatting a title as juxtaposed mathematical variables.

Thank you very much for your opinion, I will make changes@Sammy Black
